# Problem with calculating OEE via custom expression in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have one question regarding custom expressions in Spotfire. I'm trying to calculate OEE (Overall Equipment Effectiveness) via custom expression in cross table.

The problem that I'm having is that when there is more than one work order in one shift, I'm getting incorrect (random) value for OEE. I'm only getting the correct value when there is only one work order.

My question is, how to sum the OEE values when there are more then one work order in one shift via custom expression on the axis of the cross table?

Here is the table from which I'm trying to calculate OEE:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO2Cs.png)

I've tried creating Calculated column with the OEE formula and I'm always getting fixed value for all work orders, for example in my case 0.39, that's why I'm using custom expression on the cell value axis on the cross table.